# Can I use multiple --subtitutions flags in gcloud builds sbmit command?

Tags: sh, gcloud

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
gcloud builds submit ./dist                                     \
--config=./cloudbuild.yaml                                      \
--substitutions=_SUB_1=$VALUE_1,_SUB_2=$VALUE_2,_SUB_3=$VALUE_3 \
--project=$PROJECT_ID
```

This is what I'd like to do:

```
--substitutions=_SUB_1=$VALUE_1 \
--substitutions=_SUB_2=$VALUE_2 \
--substitutions=_SUB_3=$VALUE_3 \
```

Is this allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried repeating the flag to prove to yourself whether that works?

I think it doesn't and you must use your first syntax.

When parsing command-line arguments, there's a distinction between a flag `--xxx` that has a repeating value and a repeating flag `---xxx=A --xxx=B` that takes a singular value so, generally, the two aren't interchangeable (though it's logical to want these to be equivalent).

Do you want this because you're trying to script the command and encountering problems?

Comment: It seems weird, but take a look at this [Using environment variables in cloud run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables#setting). It allows you to set multiple `--set-env-vars` flags. That's where I got the idea from. It would be much nicher to write it in multiple lines rather than a long one.

Comment: Yes, it's an inconsistency. I assume, the Cloud Build SDK team chose one flag with a repeating value and the Cloud Run SDK team chose repeating flags with a single value.

Comment: Please prove to yourself (I assume but haven't tried) that you can't repeat `--substitutions` on cloud build and then, you may want to submit an issue proposing consistency: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=800102. It's reasonable to want it. This occurs elsehwere IIRC e.g. gcloud compute ... --network-interface` (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create#--network-interface). NB it's also inconsistent whether the flag is a plural (`--network-interface` when repeated on compute but `--set-env-vars` when repeated on run)